# django 1.9 tests: Able to test the whole project but fails to run individual tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a `django 1.9` app with tests that looks like this:

[image]

these `test_***` files contain `django.test.TestCase` classes, as usual.

When I test the whole project with

```
python manage.py test --keepdb
```

everything works perfectly, all tests are found and ran.

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
....................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 38 tests in 12.214s

OK
```

However, when I try to run an individual test, like so

```
python manage.py test bots.NodeTreeWalkerTests.test_regex_questions --keepdb
```

it fails:

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: NodeTreeWalkerTests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: NodeTreeWalkerTests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ImportError: No module named 'bots.NodeTreeWalkerTests'
```

It worked before, but I renamed my project, and now it doesn't work.

It looks like I've messed up some environment variables, but I changed all old name instances to the new name, and the project itself works perfectly, but this one particular issue remains.

I tried importing test cases to the `tests.__init__` file

```
from bots.tests.test_node_tree_walker import NodeTreeWalkerTests
```

but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to Izkata's comment I got the test to work with a more detailed path

```
python manage.py test bots.tests.test_node_tree_walker.NodeTreeWalkerTests.test_regex_questions
```

But why does Pycharm keep suggesting me the wrong path?

[image]

Comment: As I don't have that version of Django to double-check with, I'm not posting it as an answer - but your command looks totally wrong.  I'm not surprised it failed.  Try `bots.tests.test_node_tree_walker.NodeTreeWalkerTests.test_regex_questions`

Comment: I _think_ what you tried works for the default test runner of an old version of Django, something like 1.3 (but even then, I think only with a `tests.py` and not a `tests/` directory)

Comment: @Izkata awesome thanks, this worked! The path I had tried before was from Pycharm - don't know why it got that wrong.